# Error in elif code block

Tags: python

I am struggling to understand the following error in the code block below:

```
if o == None or t == None:
 try:
elif o == 1 and t == 1:
  c1 = c1 + 1
elif o == -1 and t == -1:
  c2 = c2 + 1
elif o == -1 and t == 1:
  i1 = i1 + 1                
elif o == 1 and t == -1:
  i2 = i2 + 1
 return (c1, i1, c2, i2)
```

---

Error :

```
elif o == 1 and t == 1:
   ^
Syntax error : invalid syntax
```

Can anyone point out what am I doing wrong? I followed correct indentation in the program.

Answer (score 5):

You appear to have a naked `try` in your code which is very much stuffing up the layout of your program.

You can certainly `try` within a code block of an `if` statement, but you need to provide the entire thing, something like:

```
if somethingOrOther():
    try:
        xyzzy = 42
    except:
        pass
elif ...
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the structure of your code correctly indented, so maybe now it's obvious what the problem is?

```
if o == None or t == None:
    try:
        elif o == 1 and t == 1:
            c1 = c1 + 1
        elif o == -1 and t == -1:
            c2 = c2 + 1 elif o == -1 and t == 1:
            i1 = i1 + 1
        elif o == 1 and t == -1:
            i2 = i2 + 1 
return (c1, i1, c2, i2)
```

Comment: You can't have `elif` blocks without an `if` block preceding them.

Comment: @volatility Yeah, exactly, maybe I should have been a bit more specific

Comment: I guess if it was obvious to @user, this question would not have been asked

Answer (score 3):

Once you fix your indentation

```
if o == None or t == None:
    try:
        elif o == 1 and t == 1:
             c1 = c1 + 1 
        elif o == -1 and t == -1:    
......
```

your code will still not work. Note how the elif is at a different indentation from the if.

You cannot splice a try into the middle of an if statement. All the elif statements must be at the same nesting/indentation level. Therefore if you open a try block inside an if or elif, you must complete it before completing that if or elif.

You'll need it like this:

```
try:
    if o is None or t is None:
        pass
    elif o == 1 and t == 1:
        c1 = c1 + 1 
    elif o == -1 and t == -1:    
......
```

Another point to make is not to compare against None using the equality operator. You should use is when comparing against the singleton None:

```
if o is None or t is None:
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful comments ! It worked when I put the try: outside the if block.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is **correct** just the format is wrong.

> Nothing to serious but format is highly effective in python, the wrong amount of whitespaces and **it could ruin your entire code**. Organization and punctuation with semicolons are also key.

Here is the right format.

```
if o == None or t == None:
    try:
        elif o == 1 and t == 1:
            c1 = c1 + 1
        elif o == -1 and t == -1:
            c2 = c2 + 1
        elif o == -1 and t == 1:
            i1 = i1 + 1                
        elif o == 1 and t == -1:
            i2 = i2 + 1

    except:
        ...

return (c1, i1, c2, i2)
```

> Great question! This will be used throughout all the time stack overflow is around. Keep it up!